# Problem with sorting by row ( special case )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, will-paginate

I have a requirement for sorting Contacts records by primary_contact_no.
My Contact fields contain primary_contact_no ,email , mobile_no.

this is no brainier....

BUT my view requires me to show **mobile_no** under *Contact Number*(view label) when **primary_contact_no** is not present.

```
Contacts.find(:all, :order => "primary_contact_no")
```

Now When i sort it by **primary_contact** , in the view , the records where these fields are absent get replaced with **mobile_no** but since they are already sorted by contact_no they appear at the bottom of the search result.

How can i combine the two results ( in case **primary_contact** is not present and carry out search on the combined record )

Is there any other solution to the problem where i can combine the row search records or something like that???

P.S.
I have used **will paginate**.

Comment: take a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce if using MySQL and try somthing like, `:order => "COALESCE(primary_contact_no,mobile_no)`

Comment: i am using postgresql.. rails 2

Comment: you should start using `Contacts.all(:order => "…")` instead of `Contacts.find(:all, :order => "…")` if you plan on upgrading to rails 3 some time

Answer (score 1):

You could order once you retrieve them from the database.

So

```
contacts = Contact.all
u.sort!{|a,b| a.con_number<=> b.con_number}
```

Then in your Contact Model

```
def con_number
  primary_contact_no||mobile_no
end
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL and PostgreSQL both have COALESCE function, so you can do something like:

```
Contacts.find(:all, :order => "COALESCE(primary_contact_no,mobile_no)")
```

to sort the records as you want. But beware, using sql functions and raw sql has its caveats. If you decide to switch databases, you have to check if each raw sql and sql function you used like this is supported in your new RDBMSI.

I would not sort the records in my application, as that means, I can not use pagination of will paginate to select limited data and have to retrieve full set of records, sort them and then use the relevant records based on pagination parameters. It will increase the response time consistently as the contacts table grows.